# comparing raw file records and sql table record in python - collapsing two fields

Tags: python, mysql

raw file contents :

```
$ cat test.txt
col1|col2|col3|col4
a|b|1|
```

whereas the sql table which needs to be updated has :

```
select * from test_table;
col1|col2|col3|col4
a|b|3|2
```

I need to collapse all these records together, final output needed is :

```
col1|col2|col3|col4
a|b|1|2
```

for parsing, I am first reading the raw file one by one record

```
dbRows=[]
ct = 0
with open('output.txt','w') as f:
    csvwriter=csv.DictWrite(csvfile,delimiter='|',fieldnames)
    flnm = open('test.txt','r')
    csvreader=csv.DictReader(flnm,delimiter='|')
    for (rowNum,row) in enumerate(csvreader)
        col1 = row['col1']
        col2 = row['col2']
        col3 = row['col3']
        col4 = row['col4']
        cursor.execute("select col1,col2,col3,col4 from test_table where col1 = '%s' and col2 = '%s';"%(col1,col2))
        table_results = cursor.fecthall()
        table_col3 = table_results['col3']
        table_col4 = table_results['col4']

        if col3 == None:
            col3=table_col3

        if col4 == None:
            col4=table_col4

        dbRow={'col1':col1, 'col2':col2,'col3':col3,'col4':col4}
        csvwriter.writerow(dbRow)
        dbRows.append(dbRow)
        ct +=1
```

Problem is : not able to get the record from the table.

Comment: What do you mean by "collapse"?

Comment: just edited the example, should be clear from that.

Comment: You want to get query result and overwrite cells in it with data from csv-like file?

Comment: And you didn't state what your problem exactly is

Comment: the sql table might have records for col1 and col2 combination already, but in case the raw file has a new updated record for the same combination, I want to use the raw file contents.

But, all the columns in raw file might not be present, so I want to extract only specific set of records and use the existing ones from the table in case the record is a blank/null.

Comment: I don't see any problems but slight typo (`=` instead of `==` in `if` conditions)